# Add multiple lines in a textblock without over writing the previous line

Tags: c#, visual-studio, textblock

I'm trying to output an array into a textblock with each element in a line using a for loop but it only outputs the final element.

I think it's over writing the current output with the next one. Is there a way I can print the entire array with each element on a new line using a single textblock? This is what I'm trying currently.

```
string nl = Environment.NewLine;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            display_all_output2.Text = (arrayid[i] + nl);
        }
```

Comment: Of course. At each loop you rewrite the Text property. At the end only the last element of the array remains. No need to loop. Use [string.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-6.0)

Comment: You need to **add** the current array value to the existing `Text`, not replace it.  The `=` is replacing the `Text` with the current array value.

Comment: What are you targeting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: Also, you might consider using `string.Join()` instead of a loop.  [Documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-6.0)

Comment: You can use [String.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-6.0) or [StringBuilder Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-6.0).

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to go about this the simplest is just to add the text onto the existing text.

```
display_all_output2.Text += (arrayid[i] + nl);
```

This is not best practice here though for two reasons, string are an immutable type, and actually have to have a new one be built in the background every time you do this, and this is in a loop so it's happening multiple times. You might not notice the speed difference on 10 loops, but there's a a few straightforward ways of dealing with appending text.

First there's the string.Join a few people mentioned.

```
string.Join(Environment.NewLine, arrayid);
```

That does it in one line instead of multiple. The other way, if you do need to loop through the array for some other reason, is with a StringBuilder.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(arrayid[i] + Environment.NewLine));
    }
```

StringBuilder are made to quickly be expanded and have the contents modified.

Edited to add: When done building the string with StringBuilder, you will usually retrieve the contents of the StringBuilder with .ToString()

```
display_all_output2.Text = sb.ToString();
```